# How can i set a default screen in using createStackNavigator combined with create createDrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Im setting the routes of my react-native app and im trying to combine createStackNavigator and createDrawerNavigator. So, one of the screens in my drawer is a stackNavigator (ex: Home, News, Images. where Images is a stackNavigator) and the stackNavigator have two other screens (ex: Feed and Grid) and im trying to set the Feed as the default screen, so i always get redirected to the Feed.

Ive tried something like: initialRouteName: 'Feed'

But if navigate to the Grid than navigate to some screen in the Drawer then comeback to the "Images" it opens the Grid and not the Feed

```
const ImagesTab = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Feed: { screen: Feed },
        Grid: { screen: Grid },
    },
    {
        headerMode: 'none',
        navigationOptions: {
            headerVisible: false,
        }
    }
)

const AppDrawer = createDrawerNavigator({

    home: { screen: Home },
    news: { screen: News },
    images: { screen: ImagesTab },
    galeria: { screen: AppTabNavigator },
},
    {
        contentComponent: DrawerContent
    }
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ought to set **initialRouteName** both of your navigators.

```
const ImagesTab = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Feed: { screen: Feed },
        Grid: { screen: Grid },
    },
    {
        headerMode: 'none',
        navigationOptions: {
            headerVisible: false,
        },
        initialRouteName: 'Feed'
    }
)

const AppDrawer = createDrawerNavigator({

    home: { screen: Home },
    news: { screen: News },
    images: { screen: ImagesTab },
    galeria: { screen: AppTabNavigator },
},
    {
        contentComponent: DrawerContent,
        initialRouteName: 'images'
    }

);
```

Comment: My drawer initialRoute is 'home'

Comment: Sorry, i understood you want that whenever you go back on your drawer, open Feed screen. So, this is enough:  `code`const ImagesTab = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Feed: { screen: Feed },
        Grid: { screen: Grid },
    },
    {
        headerMode: 'none',
        navigationOptions: {
            headerVisible: false,
        },
        initialRouteName: 'Feed'
    }
) `code`

Comment: and you should define a root navigator which is a stack navigator. https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/131#issuecomment-281493120

Answer (score 0):

I don't know If you got what you wanted on this question. But I think dropping some resources here might help someone who fall on this question later.

The thing is that you must work with what we call nested navigation, you can refer to this official doc of react navigation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators and read this section https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation